# Amazon EC2 and PostgreSQL: cannot connect due to time out error

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, psql

I think I followed any possible guide before asking here.

I am trying to remotely connect to a PostgreSQL db installed on a EC2 Linux instance (Ubuntu server 18.04, free tier if it matters).

Here are all the steps I did before hitting a wall and begging for help.

1. I connected to my instance via SSH
2. I downloaded and installed postgres following [this docs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-18-04)
3. I created a new used (umberto)
4. I created a new DB (wondermap)
5. I created a new OS user with the same name as in step 3 (umberto)
6. I connected to my new db with my new user from the server and everything woked fine
7. I edited `/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf` adding these lines:

   host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

   host all all ::/0 md5
8. I edited `/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf` changing `#listen_addresses = 'localhost'` into `listen_addresses = '*'`
9. i restarted the postgres server with `sudo service postgresql restart`
10. I added a new Inbound rule in the instance security group like so:

    TCP port:5432 source:0.0.0.0/0, ::/0

After all, I am trying to connect from my local mahine (either using pgadmin3 or psql) but I still receive a timeout error (host is hidden):

```
psql -h <PUBLIC-IP-OF-MY-INSTANCE> -U umberto -d wondermap

or even

psql -h <PUBLIC-IP-OF-MY-INSTANCE> -U postgres

psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "<PUBLIC-IP-OF-MY-INSTANCE>" and accepting
```

Doing S`ELECT version();` shows:

```
PostgreSQL 10.7 (Ubuntu 10.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0, 64-bit
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, I stil had to unblock postgres port on server's firewall.

11. `sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp`

That did the trick!